# Existe algun ide que venga con librerias multiplataforma instaladas

Tags: c, ide

Seria mejor que estar bajando un ide y agregar por ej gtk o sdl manualmente 
Programo en c.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio te irá muy bien, te dejo un enlace a la web oficial https://www.visualstudio.com/es/